# Can not add Calculated Value to Schedule

Tags: revit-api, revitpythonshell, pyrevit, revit-2015

I'm working to create Schedule on Revit by C# but Can not add Calculated Value

Create Schedule on Revit By C#

Comment: Please search the Revit API discussion forum for `schedule calculated`. I see a number of solutions there: https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/bd-p/160. Please confirm that you found the right one. Thank you!

Comment: It's not possible using API since I remember.